# Polymorphism and default implementations in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, polymorphism

Basically I have a Parent superclass which i.e is called MAMMAL. The mammal by default extends a UIImageview. Now I have tiger class which in turns extend the MAMMAL class and the mammal class has i.e a breastfeedbaby method.

In my mammal.h class, i declare the breastfeedbaby method.

Now , I want to be able to do something like adding a list of animals which extends mammal and have their own breastfeedbaby implementation, loop through and array and just cast to Mammal and do [mammal breastfeedbaby].

I would like each animal to call their own breastfeedbaby method since they all overide it but my issue is that it will call the breastfeedbaby from the mammal.m if i declare it there.

In java i can either use an interface or just have an abstract class with abstract method and have the different implementations override the method.

Does that make sense? My issue is that if i do not omit the breastfeedbaby method in mammal.m it will call the breastfeedbaby method in the mammal.m and if i do ommit the breastfeedbaby method in the mammal.m, the class will be yellow with warnings saying i did not implement the mammal.h class correctly. If I do that the animals' breastfeedbaby method is called. Should I just use a protocol here but from what I understand a protocol is not the same as an interface in java.

I don't know if it makes sense but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following scenario:

- Mammal.h: `- (void)method;`
- Mammal.m: `- (void)method { NSLog(@"Mammal"); }`
- Monkey.h: `@class Monkey : Mammal`
- Monkey.m: `- (void)method { [super method]; NSLog(@"Monkey"); }`
- Somewhere.m: `Mammal *monkey = [[Monkey alloc] init]; [monkey method];`

Should yield:

> Mammal
>
> Monkey

UPDATE: of course, you can remove the call to `[super method]` if you wish. Just showing the possibility.

Comment: Thanks this is what i have :-) . My method is actually being called. It is just that my images are not animating and i thought my method was not being called. Stupid me. I always think something else is wrong when obviously , i probably messed up my animation somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C resolves everything dynamically, so it doesn't have abstract base classes or interfaces. The closest you can get to an abstract method is to write a default implementation (in the parent class) that throws an exception.

```
@implementation Mammal

- (void)breastfeedBaby
{
    [NSException raise:@"MethodNotImplemented"
                format:@"Class %@ failed to implement required method %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}

@end
```

It would be nice to catch missing methods at compile-time, but that just isn't possible in a language with dynamic typing.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments. This is also helpful.

Comment: @dwineman: Thanks for clearing that up for me! Minor edit:[self className] should be [self class]

Answer (score 0):

Even if you cast an object as a MAMMAL, it will still call the `-breastfeedbaby` method for whatever subclass it is. This is because Objective-C uses message sending.

Comment: If i ommit the breastfeedbaby method from the mammal.m , then the animal breastfeedbaby method is called but the mammal.m class is yellow with warnings saying i did not implement the breastfeedbaby method.

Comment: What you can do in that case is implement it, but return `nil`.

Comment: Or implement it and throw an exception.